# wordpress: changing page template

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Usually to change a page template in wordpress, I just need to log in the CMS and choose a page template from a dropdown menu when editing the particular page.

My problem is I have ~100 pages and manually changing a page one by one is going to be a hassle. Is there a way to go directly to the database and do some mysql queries to change all the page template to say "News Template" instead of "Announcements Template"

I made a template called news.php and inside it I've added..

```
<?php
  /*
    Template Name: News Template
  */
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading up on Wordpress Codex here's what I came up with (I basically tweeked Frederick's answer since it was not working for me)

```
<?php
  function temp_func_templates(){
    //Note: 26 is the page_id of News page
    $args = array('child_of' => 26, 'depth' => 1);
    $children = get_pages($args);
    foreach( $children as $page ) {
      $current_template = get_post_meta( $page->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
      $new_template = 'news.php';


      if( $current_template != $new_template  && ($page->post_parent == '26')){
        update_post_meta( $page->ID, '_wp_page_template', $new_template );
      }
    }

  }
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'temp_func_templates' );

?>
```

I have a page News where it shows the 5 most current news and it is a parent of all the news pages I've created.

So, i basically took all the child pages of News and changed assigned it with a new template.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change all pages to another template, you might aswell make Wordpress do the job, by adding this to functions.php

```
function temp_func_templates(){

    foreach( get_posts('post_type=page') as $page ) {
        $current_template = get_post_meta( $page->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
        $new_template = 'news.php';

        if( $current_template != $new_template )
            update_post_meta( $page->ID, '_wp_page_template', $new_template );
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'temp_func_templates' );
```

Then removing the code, when you've confirmed it to be working.
This will check every page for it's current template data - If it's not "news.php", it'll change it.

Note that this hooks to Admin panel - To avoid visitors running these queries every pageload.
Just go to WP-Admin once - confirm it's done - Remove the code.

Comment: @Frederick, Thanks for the help. Lets just say I have other templates that's applied to other pages. Won't this overwrite their assigned templates? 

I think I'll modify your code where the if statement is so it doesnt overwrite it? I hope that works.

Comment: Yeah. You can add some if's to rule out everything you don't need set too!

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me, but I was able to figure it out after reading the WP codex. It was a minor tweek. Thanks again

Comment: You're very welcome. Please also accept the answer if it worked for you.